# COUNT value in column A + filter column B & C + > & < value column D (date)

Tags: google-sheets

I need to calculate how many rows in a range(`>=` `<=` of VALUE in column D( date value where every row has own date):
VALUE in column A(if duplicate count as 1), same VALUE in column B, same VALUE in column C.

[Spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TSVkzcffQsN6HcLdsXPSW0RVT7qqHFGpbrjKXFy4oWA/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: VIEW EXAMPLE]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or example table of what you have currently?

Comment: VIEW EXAMPLE please

Comment: do you mean count of rows with date within FROM and TO? Do you want to count only unique values from column A? (what if e.g. first row of `5` would be out of the range, but second one within it, do you want to count it?) What "same VALUE in column B" means??

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TSVkzcffQsN6HcLdsXPSW0RVT7qqHFGpbrjKXFy4oWA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The locale of your spreadsheet is Italy. This implies that comma is used for separating the fractional part of a number, as in `3,14`. Hence, the semicolon is used to separate the arguments of a command. Replacing the commas with semicolons in your formula is all that's needed;

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER( $A3:$A9 ; $C3:$C9="B"; $B3:$B9="R5"; $D3:$D9>=C11; $D3:$D9<=C12)))
```

Additionally, the formula can be slightly simplified by using `countunique`:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER( $A3:$A9; $C3:$C9="B"; $B3:$B9="R5"; $D3:$D9>=C11; $D3:$D9<=C12))
```